# Finding paired events with reshape

Tags: r, reshape, reshape2

I have a list of users and items that have been bought by them at certain times, and I want to generate a list of those pairs from the raw data. While I can and probably will write a small python script to do it, I have the nagging feeling that the reshape (or more likely reshape2) package could do this in a few lines.

In code I want the df data frame below to be transformed into the resdf data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(user=c("u1","u2","u1","u3","u2","u4","u5","u4"),
                 item=c("i1","i1","i2","i3","i2","i3","i3","i4"),
                 time=c(1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6))
> df
  user item time
1   u1   i1    1
2   u2   i1    1
3   u1   i2    2
4   u3   i3    3
5   u2   i2    4
6   u4   i3    4
7   u5   i3    5
8   u4   i4    6
> 

### some reshape code here

resdf <- data.frame(user=c("u1","u2","u4"),
                    item1=c("i1","i1","i3"),
                    item2=c("i2","i2","i4"),
                    time=c(1,1,4),
                    delt=c(1,3,2))
> pdf
  user item1 item2 time delt
1   u1    i1    i2    1    1
2   u2    i1    i2    1    3
3   u4    i3    i4    4    2
```

Are there any reshape wizards who can help me with this?

Comment: Where's is the desired output for users `u4` and `u5`?

Comment: u3 and u5 would be empty because they only bought one item, and thus there is no pair to generate. Delt is the different in time between the events. But I am not too worried about that, should be easy once I figure out how to generate the pairs.

Comment: Excellent. I will try them both out with some largish data sets (almost 5 million events) and award the solution to the one that works best.

Comment: Both answers are highly useful to me, but the merge solution worked immediately and completely without warnings, whereas the dcast solution is a lot harder to grok and has a lot of warnings and NAs (also had to use the full name dcast.data.table to get it to work with my library). 

However I suspect the dcast solution might work a lot better for very large datasets since it is using data tables. 
Going to study them a bit more, if you don't mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you merge  rows with duplicated `user` values back to the ones with no dupes you get the information you need and then a bit of massaging delivers the desired arrangement:

```
> merge(df[!duplicated(df$user), ], df[duplicated(df$user), ], by="user")
  user item.x time.x item.y time.y
1   u1     i1      1     i2      2
2   u2     i1      1     i2      4
3   u4     i3      4     i4      6
> inter <- merge(df[!duplicated(df$user), ], df[duplicated(df$user), ], by="user")
> inter$delt <- inter$time.y-inter$time.x
> inter[ , c(1,2,4,3,6)]
  user item.x item.y time.x delt
1   u1     i1     i2      1    1
2   u2     i1     i2      1    3
3   u4     i3     i4      4    2
```

Comment: That's a nice and simple solution. Good thinking.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my attempt using the `data.table` package (which also has a `dcast` function)

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df), user, item) # sorting by user and time so `head` and `diff` will work
df[, `:=`(indx = paste0("item", seq_len(.N)), # Creating all the needed variables
          indx2 = .N,
          time2 = head(time, 1),
          delt = diff(time)), 
     user]

dcast(df[indx2 > 1L], # Decasting by the modified item column
              user + time2 + delt ~ indx, 
              value.var = "item")

#    user time2 delt item1 item2
# 1:   u1     1    1    i1    i2
# 2:   u2     1    3    i1    i2
# 3:   u4     4    2    i3    i4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(user) %>%
  filter(n() == 2) %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  summarise(
    item1 = first(item),
    item2 = last(item),
    delt = last(time) - first(time),
    time = first(time)
    ) %>%
  select(user, item1, item2, time, delt)
```